# Not all columns displayed using pandas to display sqlite3 query results

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

SQL noob here. I am trying to feed a pandas dataframe with SQL data and explore data with the following setup. But the output does not give all column headers. Shouldn't it be possible to display all column headers without having to open the database itself without sqlite studio?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('hubway.db')

def run_query(query):
    return pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)

query = 'SELECT * FROM stations LIMIT 10

run_query(query)
```

gives:

```
   id         ...                         lng
0   3         ...                  -71.100812
1   4         ...                  -71.069616
2   5         ...                  -71.090179
3   6         ...                   -71.06514
4   7         ...                  -71.044624
```

and so on. I tried to use the curor object to try without the pandas dataframe

```
crsr.execute('.schema stations')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Really not sure where to go from here, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
```

by default, pandas will show you only x columns, you can alter that value...

other parameters:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Comment: @codename_panda - if you could give the answer an upvote, i would be happy

Comment: Rather than displaying the data table with headers it is just simpler to use: pd.DataFrame.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True) to show all columns

Comment: I tried to right after you replied and now but I got a popup saying that since I have a reputation score less than 15 it is recorded but wont publicly update the answers score.